# gson invoking standard deserialization in custom deserializer

Tags: java, json, gson

Is it possible to write a json deserializer in gson that invokes the default behaviour first and then i can do some post processing on my object. For example:

```
public class FooDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Foo> {
    public Foo deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {      
        Foo foo = context.deserialize(json, typeOfT);//Standard deserialization call?????
        foo.doSomething();
        return foo();
    }
}
```

I am using gson 1.3 (I cannot use any other version as i can only use the versions in the corporate 
repository)

thanks

Comment: Realized that there is a general issue http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=43

Comment: Nice work Asim. Can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Comment: @Kev Please re-open this question. Obviously it was releveant for at leat 8 people that gave it an upvote, including me (the 9th person).

Comment: @Guy - it's a wee bit "write this code for me" which is why it got flagged up for mod attention and I closed it, way back then. Popularity isn't always a good indicator of a good question which I'm sure you'll know. Just so you know, I retired as a diamond mod last year so I can't re-open questions. Only another diamond mod or group of users with sufficient privileges can re-open. Also OP could have flagged to re-open so he/she could post an answer.

Comment: Good question. If I have time I'll try to solve it later

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by implementing custom TypeAdapterFactory for your object (say CustomClass.class) to be deserialized as below.

```
 public class CustomTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    public final TypeAdapter create(Gson gson, TypeToken type) {
     return new TypeAdapter() {
            @Override 
            public void write(JsonWriter out, Object value) throws IOException {
                JsonElement tree = delegate.toJsonTree(value);
                //add code for writing object
            }

            @Override 
            public Object read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                JsonElement tree = elementAdapter.read(in);
                //Add code for reading object
            }
        };
    }
  }
```

And then registering it with Gson as

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(CustomClass.class,new CustomTypeAdapterFactory()).create();
```

Comment: And where do the `delegate` and `elementAdapter` variables come from?

Comment: @flawyte, this example is missing a single line before `return new TypeAdapter`: delegate adapter creation. This can be a builtin adapter, for example, `final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = TypeAdapters.ENUM_FACTORY.create(gson, type);`

Comment: You can use `gson.getDelegateAdapter(YOUR_FACTORY_CLASS.this, type)` to get the value for `delegate` and `elementAdapter`.

In the instance above, it would be `gson.getDelegateAdapter(CustomTypeAdapterFactory.this, type)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourDeserializer<Foo> extends FooDeserializer<Foo>  
 {  
     public Foo deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)    throws JsonParseException {       
        Foo foo = super.deserialize(json, typeOfT,context);  
        foo.doSomething();  //put logic   
        return foo();  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://gsonfire.io

It's a library I made that extends Gson to handle cases like Post-serialization and Post-deserialization

Also it has many other cool features that I've needed over time with Gson.

Answer (score 0):

Here's full implementation based on incomplete answer provided by @user1556622 and discussion in  [code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=43](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/43).

As a result we can serialize list of abstract `Field` objects and smoothly deserialize it independent on concrete implementation of specific `Field` and its hierarchy depth.

```
class MyClass { //class which we would like to serialiaze/deserialize
   List<Field> fields; //field is an hierarchy of classes
}


/**
 * Purpose of this adapter is simple:
 * 1) put during serialization in all Field objects additional property describing class
 * 2) during deserialization invoke (based on class info) necessary deserializer to create class
 */

public class FieldTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    private static final String CLASS_META_KEY="clz";
    Gson gson;
    TypeToken<?> type;
    TypeAdapter<Field> fieldAdapter;
    TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter;
    TypeAdapterFactory taf;

    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        if (!Field.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType()))
            return null; // this class only serializes 'Field' and its subtypes

        this.type=type;
        this.gson=gson;
        this.taf=this;
        fieldAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(taf, TypeToken.get(Field.class));
        elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);
        TypeAdapter<T> result = new FieldTypeAdapter<T>();
        result.nullSafe();
        return result;
    }

    class FieldTypeAdapter<T> extends TypeAdapter<T> {

        public FieldTypeAdapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter out, Object value) throws IOException {
            if(value instanceof Field) {
                JsonObject object = fieldAdapter.toJsonTree((Field )value).getAsJsonObject();
                object.addProperty(CLASS_META_KEY, value.getClass().getCanonicalName());
                elementAdapter.write(out, object);
            }
            else {
                elementAdapter.write(out, (JsonElement) value);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            JsonObject object = elementAdapter.read(in).getAsJsonObject();
            if (object.has(CLASS_META_KEY)) {
                String className=object.get(CLASS_META_KEY).getAsString();
                try {
                    Class<?> clz = Class.forName(className);
                    TypeAdapter<?> adapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(taf, TypeToken.get(clz));
                    return (T) adapter.fromJsonTree(object);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    return (T )fieldAdapter.fromJsonTree(object);
                }
            }
            else
                return (T )elementAdapter.fromJsonTree(object);
        }
    }
}
```

Registration of factory:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new FieldTypeAdapterFactory())
                .create();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FooDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Foo> {
public Foo deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {      
    Foo foo=new Gson().fromJson(json, Foo.class); // use default Gson object
    foo.doSomething();
    return foo;
}
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to allocate new Gson instance on every deserialization.